# Android studio 3.5 : logcat not showing any log

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5

I have clear all log after that I faced issue in logcat. I don't know it's 3.5 issue or not.

I have tried below steps.

- Go to Run -> Edit Configurations.
- Select the Miscellaneous tab
- select the following options

  - Show logcat automatically.
  - Clear log before launch.

After that Invalidated Caches/Restart Android Studio. Still not able to show logcat.

Also tried with"No Filter"
Can any one help ?

Comment: What does it say when your run `adb devices` in the command line? Does that show all the devices which are connected?

Comment: yes it shows all device which are connected

Comment: Is logcat completely gone after clicking logcat tab from bottom bar or is it just the logs that is missing inside the logcat tab.

Comment: logcat tab is avilable, in device list it shows all online device, also open app list availble. only logs are missing

Comment: maybe try with another device.

Comment: yes working on another device but device in which it stops showing logcat still not able to see logs while I connect that device.